# Installing mahout and importing it to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu, mahout, root

This is my first stack overflow question. Normally I don't have to ask because it's already been addressed elsewhere, but I've been trying to figure this out for nearly a week and can't do it.

I have maven.

Since the guide on the mahout website basically say "Installing mahout: step 1 - you should install mahout", I had to look elsewhere for a guide. I followed the guide here because it seemed simple enough and made sense:

http:// harish11g.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/configuring-mahout-clustering-hadoop.html

However, if I don't run

svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk as sudo, it won't work.

Similarly, if I don't use sudo for

mvn install

It won't work, failing at the mahout-core stage of the build.

Using sudo, the build succeeds, but because my useraccount did not do the build (root did it) when I import the project to eclipse there are errors. Here is a screenshot: 
http://i.imgur.com/MEp3lA0.png
Can I proceed with using mahout despite these errors, or how can I fix them? If I have done something wrong and should reinstall mahout in a different way, I'm happy to but I need to know exactly what I've done wrong.

I tried using maven to install mahout in my home directory and it didn't work there either. My thinking was that I wouldn't need superuser permissions to use the directory, so I didn't use sudo. I also tried changing the permissions of /opt to allow my useraccount to make changes. It still failed, and I've had to use sudo again and the eclipse errors are still showing.

I don't understand why in every guide I've seen online this hasn't been a problem. What could be so different about my user account that means I can't simply use

mvn install

to get mahout downloaded and installed?

If anyone could explain this is in a simple step-by-step way that would be amazing, because I really don't know why I'm having such trouble with this. Also, I've only been using Ubuntu in earnest for the past few weeks (although I had some experience with it over the past year, never really used it for anything serious) for this project, so you'll understand if I'm not immediately aware of some terminal commands or other linux tricks that to others may seem obvious.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `ls -l` on that directory in the terminal. Does the listed username match the one you are logged in (and running eclipse), or even the username in the terminal prompt?

This is bad: I am logged in as jj and I am **trying to edit files owned by hduser**:

```
jj@jj-ThinkPad-T420 ~/dev/crap $ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hduser audio 0 Jun 16 23:37 afile
```

So we change the ownership of directory to jj:

```
jj@jj-ThinkPad-T420 ~/dev $ sudo chown -R jj:jj crap
```

All-clear to compile into this directory:

```
jj@jj-ThinkPad-T420 ~/dev/crap $ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jj jj 0 Jun 16 23:37 afile
```

---

Image depicts Eclipse unable to write compiled classes to a directory owned by somebody else; while Eclipse (and rest of desktop) is owned by you. Root user can do anything on any directory, hence sudo works.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to help solve one of the errors. At least, it changed from an error to a warning. 
... 
(Access "/opt/mahout_trunk/src/conf" directory outside of project base directory. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)) ...

It occurred to me that changing the permissions of everything in the mahout_trunk folder would solve a bunch of the errors, but whenever I change any of the file access permissions from -- to read and write, it changes back. I don't understand why Ubuntu hates me so much!

Comment: I seem to have been able to get rid of all the errors, although everything except mahout-distribution and mahout have red exclamation marks to indicate a build path error. mahout-math has a yellow warning  triangle. I think I might just get on with coding and see how it goes.